# Inconsistent request timings in ASP.NET WebAPI and IIS

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, performance, iis, asp.net-web-api

### Problem

I am testing the performance of one of our AngularJS + ASP.NET WebAPI applications. The strange thing I am observing is that **the exact same queries are executed with different timings** in Fiddler.

This behavior is observed not only on the server but in my local machine, too.

### Details

The application is tested using Chrome and is written in ASP.NET WebAPI (`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi version 5.2.2`) with `Angular JS version 1.3.8`.

The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 and IIS 7.5.

My local machine is Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2014.

I've noticed that the exact same queries are executed with different timings according to **Fiddler** (*the queries in blue are the same and the queries in white are another type of exact same queries*):

[image: Fiddler requests]

For example the detailed timing of **query number 26** is:

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      583        (headers:517; body:66)
Bytes Received:  3,844      (headers:260; body:3,584)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    17:26:25.099
ClientBeginRequest: 17:27:26.544
GotRequestHeaders:  17:27:26.544
ClientDoneRequest:  17:27:26.544
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    17:26:25.102
FiddlerBeginRequest:    17:27:26.544
ServerGotRequest:   17:27:26.544
ServerBeginResponse:    17:27:26.554
GotResponseHeaders: 17:27:26.554
ServerDoneResponse: 17:27:26.554
ClientBeginResponse:    17:27:26.554
ClientDoneResponse: 17:27:26.554

    Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.010
```

And the detailed timings of the **query number 28** is:

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      583        (headers:517; body:66)
Bytes Received:  3,844      (headers:260; body:3,584)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    17:26:25.099
ClientBeginRequest: 17:27:29.104
GotRequestHeaders:  17:27:29.104
ClientDoneRequest:  17:27:29.104
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    17:26:25.102
FiddlerBeginRequest:    17:27:29.104
ServerGotRequest:   17:27:29.104
ServerBeginResponse:    17:27:29.616
GotResponseHeaders: 17:27:29.616
ServerDoneResponse: 17:27:29.616
ClientBeginResponse:    17:27:29.616
ClientDoneResponse: 17:27:29.616

    Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.512
```

And as I said they are exactly the same queries (the same headers, the same data, etc.).

The query 28 is executed 1-2 seconds after the query 26.

### Questions

**What can be the main reason for such behavior? Where should I search for the problem?** The strange thing is that the query is first fast and then slow and then it is fast again, etc. There is no reason for me to thing that the problem is related to data caching.

**How to precise test the timings on the server to find this difference between `0.010` and `0.512` seconds?** The difference is more than 50 times.

Comment: are you using async methods?

Comment: No, I don't use `async` :)

Comment: Try making your actions async. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I wonder if you are running into a connection pooling problem, either in IIS or your DB.  If your requests are spaced out in a certain way you could cause request queuing, meaning that the first request would appear fast while subsequent ones would be slower (because they had to wait on the previous ones to finish).  What happens if you increase the connection pool size for your DB?  What happens if you cause an artificial delay between each request of say 10 seconds?

Comment: You will never get consistent timing on an application. Things like memory, cpu and network all affect this. What you need to do is look at the average of your tests. Then identify the bottleneck. Create a list of fixes. Implment the fixes one at a time testing each fix and measuring the average again. Looking for consistent timing is impossible.

Comment: I guess there are a few questions: is your DB under any kind of load? From other apps/ other requests? Is this the only request being made at this time ?

Comment: The exact same times are also present in my localhost testing (where this is the only application and queries running). So I don't thing the load has impact here.

Comment: When you say the queries are exactly the same, does that mean any parameters passed are exactly the same or could this be a parameter sniffing problem in SQL Server? Take a look at SQL Trace or Profiler

Comment: can you post your code in endpoint `/GetQuestion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an angular problem, but here's how I'd go about troubleshooting this:

1. Use something like this [chrome extension for a REST API client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) to make requests to your endpoint. (you could also use something like: http://jmeter.apache.org/ but it's more complex to setup)
2. Run this 20 times and save the times.
3. Empty the database and just populate the tables that you need for this request - just a few rows of data.
4. Run the tool 20 times - store the times. Are they consistent ? If at this point they're not consistent I would look to the code as being the culprit.

   - are you calling any external services ?
   - is the service doing anything else when loading the data, apart from executing a query ?
   - use a profiler like dotTrace to see what's taking more time than it should. (actually you should use this from the start)
5. If the times are still consistent, load more data in the database until times start being inconsistent. Then profile the queries and start optimizing them.

Right now, by how inconsistent the timings are I would assume that the service does something else when loading that data: an external service call .. something.

Comment: This does seem a plausible first step for the OP, but to be honest there is far to many variables at play here to make this truly useful - he is going to be better running a profiler such as dotTrace, Glimpse or even both to truly point him in the direction of his issue, otherwise he risks going down false positive rabbit holes by comparing his own test timings.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it would be very helpful if you could share with us the code that's being executed on the server, and whats the difference between the odd and even numbered requests.

I am making a lot of assumptions here, so please excuse any silly mistakes.

**I have seen this kind of behavior before**, in that case it had to do with **SqlServer's Execution Plan Caching**.

You can find a whole lot of info about this on the Internet, in short terms, before executing a query the SqlServer's engine do some calculations and decide what's the optimal way to retrieve the data for that query. This adds an additional burden to your query's time, SqlServer knows that and cache that execution plan so it can reuse it later.

I don't know all the details about it, but if I had to guess, I'd say that something is invalidating that cache so it need to be recalculated every once in a while. Common causes for this would be different `order by` and `join` clauses, that may happen depending on the data sent to the method.

Another **possibility** is that the **query´s result** itself is **being cached**, and it becomes invalid after some time.

As I said, it's a wild guess without looking at the code, but I really think it would be a good idea to check this out.

One simple way to test it is to check if the times vary if you send the exact same request over and over again, repeatedly, without sending a different one in the meantime.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You write "the exact same queries", but what exactly happens in these queries?

Are you querying a SQL server database?

How does the statement look like?

What else are you doing in your query?

There are so many possible influences, so in order to make an educated guess, I'd need some more detailed information about your queries.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check/note:

1). Have you installed Glimpse? http://getglimpse.com/  if not I would install that from nuget, this will give you an insight into the full pipeline and help you trace where these delays are coming from.

*** more general performance tips below **

2). do you have debug disabled in web config on publish to your server? if not do that first. I would expect your local pc to behave slightly differently to the server, I presume you are using iis express on your local dev pc? which has different performance characteristics than iis on the server (I would not expect this though) hence don't be overly guided by this. Glimpse is going to be your best friend here :-)

3). As above, the same applies to session state. If you don't have a very good reason to use it, turn it off (it's on by default) - it can be a performance killer in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're seeing one of the following:

1. IIS app pool recycle / cleanup (this can happen when setup to recycle once everything is closed)
2. .NET GC collection (unlikely)
3. SQL Server related delays (query execution plan caching and in memory data)

To rule out #3 try running the SQL Server profiler at the same time as fiddler and see if you can identify the delay from the database (either it will confirm it's within the database, or it will confirm that the database responds the same in both instances).

With #2 there's not much you can really do other than try to reduce memory footprint and reuse data structures; but as mentioned above it's not likely to be the cause of issue.

With #1 you should be able to make changes to the IIS configuration to ensure that this is not happening.